Using PDFClown to apply darken blend mode on all text and path elements in a PDF document
I am trying to utilize the PDFClown.NET library to create a PDF post processing exe that applies "Darken" blend mode to all Text and Path elements on all the pages of a document.
I couldn't find any sample code in the library's samples that demonstrates how to edit individual elements, only parsing and using a content scanner are demonstrated.
I tried using ChatGPT to generate a function, but that didn't work of course. It gave me a response using nonexciting objects:
 public void ApplyDarkenBlendMode(string inputPdf, string outputPdf)
        {
            // Open the input PDF
            using (File inputFile = new File(inputPdf))
            {
                Document document = inputFile.Document;

                // Iterate through all the pages
                foreach (Page page in document.Pages)
                {
                    ApplyDarkenBlendModeToPage(page);
                }

                // Save the modified PDF to the output file
                using (File outputFile = new File())
                {
                    document.File.Save(outputPdf, SerializationModeEnum.Standard);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ApplyDarkenBlendModeToPage(Page page)
        {
            // Get the content context of the page
            var contentContext = page.Contents;

            // Create a scanner for the page
            ContentScanner scanner = new ContentScanner(contentContext);

            // Iterate through the content objects
            while (scanner.MoveNext())
            {
                ContentObject contentObject = scanner.Current;

                // Check if the content object is a text or path object
                if (contentObject is Text || contentObject is PaintPath)
                {
                    ApplyBlendMode(scanner);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ApplyBlendMode(ContentScanner scanner)
        {
            var state = scanner.State;
            state.BlendMode = new List<BlendModeEnum> { BlendModeEnum.Darken };

            // Insert the ExtGState before the current content object
            scanner.Insert(new SetExtGState(state)); // <---- SetExtGState class does not exist
        }

I wonder if this is even possible using this library, I'm open to other approaches, even using other language (java and python are ok with me).
Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

It looks like version 0.1.1 had a SetExtGState operation, but even that did not accept a ContentScanner.GraphicsState. In later PdfClown versions there is a ApplyExtGState.
